# Does the less than symbol in SQL serve another purpose other than being a operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I had a vendor write a script for us and we are receiving errors pertaining to the line

`WHERE 1=1 AND student.calendarID = <selected Calendar>`.

I have never seen the syntax `"<selected abc>"`. May someone please explain this to me? Its returning an error for that line as well. I'm using MS SQL Server.

```
SELECT DISTINCT student.personID
FROM student
join TranscriptCourse tc on tc.personID = student.personID
join TranscriptCourse tc2 on tc2.personID = tc.personID and tc.coursenumber = tc2.coursenumber
WHERE 1=1 AND student.calendarID = <selected Calendar>
AND student.endYear = <selected Year>
AND student.structureID = <selected Schedule>
and tc.gpavalue > 69 and tc2.gpavalue > 69
and tc.transcriptID > tc2.transcriptID
and tc.grade in ('09','10','11','12')
and tc2.grade in ('09','10','11','12')
```

Comment: it is intended as a placeholder for you to put your own value in...in other words...delete <selected Year> and put in your own value like 2020

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like incorectly used [Template Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/template/replace-template-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15)

If used properly in format `<parametername, parametertype, defaulvalue>` eg `<SelectedCalendar, int , 0>` you can then use Query > Spefify Values for Template Parameters or `Ctrl+Shift+M` shortcut and you'll get a window where you can fill values for each template:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Angle brackets are common computer science & software engineering programming language definition meta-characters, aka characters of the [notation used to talk about programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_specification), aka a character of a meta-language, aka meta-notation. (Not to be confused with a different meaning for [characters treated specially compared to other characters by a system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter).) In informal communication about programs our metalanguage tends to be natural language plus bits stolen from more formal notations.

Typically `<x>` means a generic expression of type x that you would replace by program text.

So `<selected Schedule>` would just mean some language text for a value identifying a a schedule. It's pseudo-code for a parameter.